# Правильная стратегия

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте!

Задали на лабораторную вот такую задачку. Решения не прошу, а вот несколько подсказок мне не помешает. Задача:

> Играют два игрока. Есть полоска шириной 1 на N>=2010 клеток. Первый может закрасить 2, 4 или 6 рядом стоящих клеток (в любом месте полоски), второй 3, 6 или 9. Выигрывает тот, кто закрасит последний (второму не хватит места). Кто выиграет при правильной стратегии?

Comment: Извиняюсь, клетки должны закрашиваться подряд.

Comment: При правильной - любой выиграет =)

Comment: какой-то философский вопрос =/  
Количество возможных вариантов прямопропорционально числу N. Но нам не интерестен весь отрезок, ведь количество возможных вариантов концовки игры ограничено, и можно сразу начать рассматривать конечный участок полосы.

Comment: конечный - это сколько клеток осталось?)

Comment: Интересно, кто-нибудь кроме меня заметил, что закрашивать можно в любом месте полоски?;)

Comment: Интересно, что многие заметили комментарий автора:  
>> Извиняюсь, клетки должны закрашиваться подряд.

Comment: У-ух как все набросились на эту задачу!

Comment: @Алексей Лобанов, ну дык рабочее время - кто-то тут головоломки решает, кто-то хабр читает... надо же чем-то заняться...

Comment: @vitaliymaz, у нас принято отмечать правильный ответ, или сообщать, чем он вам не угодил.

Comment: Подряд - это как? От края полосы, или произвольный непрерывный отрезок?

Answer (score 2):

**Егор**, лучше всего эта тема раскрыта у Шеня:

1) А. Шень. Игры и стратегии с точки зрения математики (c1) 2-е изд., М.: МЦНМО, 2008, 40 с., ISBN 978-5-94057-432-3 [(pdf, 0.3M)](http://www.mccme.ru/free-books/shen/shen-games.pdf)

А здесь то же самое + много чего ещё:

2) А. Шень. Программирование: теоремы и задачи (c1) 2-е изд., М.: МЦНМО, 2004, 296 с. [(pdf.zip, 1.6M)](ftp://ftp.mccme.ru/users/shen/progbook2/progbookpdf.zip)

Comment: Первая ссылка не туда. [Так правильнее](http://www.mccme.ru/free-books/shen/shen-games.pdf), впрочем и указанная книжка полезная.

Comment: Спасибо, Юрий, со ссылкой промахнулся, теперь исправил.

Answer (score 1):

[[@teanЫЧ](/users/5098/tean%D1%8B%D1%87)](/users/5098/tean%D1%8B%D1%87)

осталось 9 клеток

ход 1ого

- если он закрасит 6 клеток - он проиграл
- если 4 - остается 5 клеток
- если 2 - остается 7 клеток

осталось 5 клеток или 7

ход 2ого

- если он закрасит 3 клетки - он проиграл
- остается число - меньше чем он может закрасить по правилам.

Comment: >> осталось 9 клеток  
>> если 2 - остается 8 клеток

Насколько мне известно, 9 - 2 = 7, а не 8.  

Зачем рассматривать все варианты, если автор указал, что рассматривается "правильная" стратегия, которая ведет к победе, а не рандомная?

>> осталось 5 клеток или 8
>> ход 2ого
>> если он закрасит 3 клетки - он проиграл  

Ну в моей табличке знак "-" означает, что игрок в любом случае проигрывает, так как нет победного хода.

Comment: поправил, так это не все варианты, это возможный сценарий, размышления игрока, который должен сделать ход

Comment: Ну да, я бы мог нарисовать полную таблицу, содержащую ВСЕ возможные варианты развития событий, но ответ сабж предполагает выжимку из победных ходов.

Answer (score 1):

**задача второго - нехватка клеток для первого:** 
0 или 1 (свободных клеток). чтоб получить такой результат второму игроку нужно свести игру к такому количеству свободных клеток:

`0+3, 0+6, 0+9, 1+3, 1+6, 1+9 -> 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10`

**задача первого - нехватка клеток для второго:**
0-2 (свободных клеток), значит нужно свести к такому количеству свободных:

`0+2, 0+4, 0+6, 1+2, 2+4, 3+6, 2+2, 2+4, 2+6 -> 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9`

логично предположить что надо ходить так чтоб противник своим ходом не мог придти ни к одному из этих вариантов (получается просчитывать надо с конца до текущего количества свободных клеток).

прибавив к этим результатам ход противника мы получим варианты к котором надо свести противника к предпоследнему ходу (итд итп).

p.s. т.к. иногда комбинации совпадают (как 0+4 и 2+2) понятно что разные пути будут сводиться в конце игры всего к 6 вариантам окончания (как для первого так и для второго). то достаточно просчитать несколько ходов чтоб разобратся при каком количестве оставшихся свободных клеток имеет смысл "включатся в борьбу" (хотя вполне вероятно что ограничивать противника надо еще с начала игры, но тогда много вычислений)

Comment: Нет смысла "бороться" на протяжении всей полоски. Главное первым встать на нужную ячейку среди последних десяти пустых. А об этом можно начать думать за 20-30 клеток до конца. Доходим до нужной клетки, смотрим на таблицу из моего ответа, и радуемся/не радуемся жизни.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, задача решается так (только надо проверку выхода за границы массивов добавить):

```
bool res[2][N] = { {0,0}, {0,0} };

for (unsigned q=2; q<=n; ++q)
{
  res[0][q] = !res[1][q-2] || !res[1][q-4] || !res[1][q-6];
  res[1][q] = !res[0][q-3] || !res[0][q-6] || !res[0][q-9];
}

cout << (res[0][n] ? "First wins" : "Second wins");
```

Это при условии, что вся полоса закрашивается подряд. Если предполагается закрашивание произвольного непрерывного отрезка, то неожиданно появляется двухмерность и там будет более сложное решение.

Впрочем, нет, во втором случае даже считать не надо, там есть выигрышная стратегия для первого игрока при длине полосы хотя бы 4: пропускаем 2 клетки от левого края и закрашиваем следующие 2. Эти 2 противник закрасить не сможет, поскольку у него минимум 3. Временно забываем про эти клетки и играем как угодно на оставшейся справа части полосы. В какой-то момент, играть на ней станет невозможно, причём, поскольку минимум 2 у нас, если мы не сможем там ничего закрасить, то и противник - тоже. Если правая полоса закончилась на нашем ходе, закрашиваем первые 2 клетки и побеждаем (если на чужом, то мы уже победили). Варианты меньше 4 клеток перебираем: очевидно, что 2 и 3 первый тоже выигрывает, а 1 - проигрывает. Значит первый игрок проигрывает только на полосе из 1 клетки.